# MaskedTextProvider c#

Tags: c#

What is the masked text provider used for? Why is it different from regex?

Is it possible to translate the regex format to mask or vise versa ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A masked edit area forces the user to fill the field in a certain way: e.g. a mask that looks like ### will only allow a maximum of 3 numbers to be entered.

A regular expression, on the other hand, is normally only checked for after the user has entered all the text. The validation happens too late to provide feedback on a character by character basis.

Answer (score 0):

A masked edit provides an input mask, with optional separators and placeholders. Users can only input data in the format supplied. As an extra you can set the mask type to Date or Time, so data is also validated for that particlar type.